# Why aren't my percentages equally spaced?

Tags: d3.js

I don't know why the percentages on this graph aren't displayed equally (on mouseover).

https://jsfiddle.net/wewffdce/

The distance between the numbers and the polygonal shapes seem to vary proportionally to the expressed amount.

This is odd because I set a fixed number `+ 0.15` on line 759 and 760 (and 779/780 for the 2nd grid) for the `x` and `y` attributes.

```
.attr("x", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value + 0.15) * Math.cos(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2) })
.attr("y", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value + 0.15) * Math.sin(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2) })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add the fixed number outside the scale method? I.e. add 0.15 after scaling, not before scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an impression, the distance doesn't vary.

You can clearly see this if you set the texts to be centralised at the x and y positions:

```
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.style("dominant-baseline", "central")
```

And hover over `Bonpoint`: https://jsfiddle.net/jbbonyfw/

In the fiddle I reduced the y value to `rScale(d.value + 0.05)`.

Comment: Thanks (as always) for the clever addition Gerardo Furtado. The `.style("dominant-baseline", "central")` line is very useful. Regarding the tips of the path, I don't see any change...at all. https://imgur.com/LItjGAh

Comment: That's funny, it was changing when I first forked the fiddle... anyway, maybe it's just my fertile imagination.